# Animating a databound progressbar in Silverlight declaratively (no code-behind)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding

How does one animate a ProgressBar whose Value property is databound?

```
<ProgressBar Height="25" Margin="5" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding CurrentProgress}">
```

My data source would probably "jump" from value to value, usually from user input; for example - user performs action, and the progress bar jumps 20 points. I would want to be able to take the new number for ProgressBar.Value and smooth it over in the animation. Let's say the new value is 50 and the old value is 20. I would want some sort of XAML markup to dictate that the UI to smoothly slides from 20 to 50.

I want to do this declaratively with no code-behind. I'm fairly sure it's possible but I can't seem to fit in the pieces together. I have looked into Storyboards, but don't know how to trigger a storyboard when data changes. I have also looked into the TransitioningContentControl but am unsure how to link the transition with the ProgressBar control.

Comment: How are you expecting the animation to work? From what you've said so far, the obvious answer would be that your data source for the CurrentProgress property needs to change over time.

Comment: My data source would probably "jump" from value to value, usually from user input; for example - user performs action, and the progress bar jumps 20 points. I feel like changing the value over time in my data source would require code-behind. Is this possible in XAML markup only?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add animation in ProgressBars Template event triger

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RangeBase.ValueChanged">
 <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnValueChanged1}"/>
</EventTrigger>
```